# Can a function call be dynamic / based on caller function's parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, method-call

First of all, I'm sorry if this question has been asked a lot. I have tried to look for a solution and phrase my question in ten different ways, but I still can't find anything that applies to my question. I am fairly new to coding javascript, so I'm not entierly sure what to search for either.

So my situation is this:

I'm building an app that has a number of popups that will be displayed.
I'm writing in MVC format.

```
function showPopup(whichPopup){
   let mainPage = document.getElementById('mainPage');
   let html = '';

      if (whichPopup == 'report'){
          popupReport();
      }
}
```

The **popupReport()** function returns the popup content/HTML, and then the rest of 
my **showPopup()** function makes the popup. The *whichPopup* attribute is 'report' in this case.

This works fine for now, but I'm in the process of adding more popup types, and instead of having multiple if-statements regarding the content, I would like to run the function that is relevant to the string coming from *whichPopup*.

Sidenote: the string coming from *whichPopup* is not capitalized and later in this writeup attempt to call it with the string capitalized. In my code I have written functions that capitalize it and send a different value, but I just simplified it here. In other words, capitalization is not the issue.

I was thinking about making a **fetchPopupContent(whichPopup)** function, which would run the corresponding function, f.ex. **popupReport()** , but I cannot seem to find out how to do it.

The most basic case I tried was to make a variable like this:

```
var popupContent = 'popup' + whichPopup + '();';
```

But I couldn't find out how to call on it.

I also tried to make an array with whichPopup as the value of the only array slot, and call on it like this:

```
function fetchPopupContent(whichPopup){
    var popupType = {
        'selectedType' : whichPopup,
    }

    popupType['selectedType']();

}
```

This didn't work either, and the error I got was "cannot read property of 'selectedType'". I also tried the same code without the **'**s.

Any ideas as to how I can define which function to call?

Comment: I fixed your last attempt like this: `function fetchPopupContent(whichPopup) {
  var popups = {
    popup1: function() { alert('POPUP 1'); },
    popup2: function() { alert('POPUP 2'); }
  };
  popups[whichPopup]();
}

fetchPopupContent('popup1');`

Comment: I have no idea, why @Quentin points you to an "eval" answer. Arrays work fine for you problem. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/xbtLgpmn/

Comment: @ceving — The accepted answer on the duplicate question recommends the use of arrays or objects.